# Resolve $http promise object when data = false but status code returns 200

Tags: angularjs

I have a `$http service` that checks if a user exists on the database or not. Problem is that even if the user does not exist and the `data = false`, the status code still returns 200

```
       videoStoreApp.factory('UserApi', function($http){

        var myService = {};

        myService.login = function(username,password){
               return $http({
               method: 'GET',
               url: 'app/services/user/getUser.php',
               params: {username: username,
                        password: password}
           }).then(function(data){

                   var obj = {
                    complete: true,
                    data: data.data
                   };
               if(obj.data === false)
               {
                   return false;

               }

                return obj;
           });

        };    
        return myService;
```

Below is my loginModal service code. I would like to stop the transition from happening if the user log in fails.

```
       videoStoreApp.service('loginModal', function ($uibModal, $rootScope) 
           {

          function assignCurrentUser (user) {
            $rootScope.currentUser = user;
           return user;
          }

          return function() {
            var instance = $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl: 'app/views/loginModalTemplate.html',
              controller: 'LoginModalCtrl',
               controllerAs: 'LoginModalCtrl'
            });

            return instance.result.then(assignCurrentUser);

            };

            });
```

Comment: What is your question? If a user does not exist, you probably want to implement the backend to respond with status 404, or you have the option to handle obj.data === false case in your service.

Comment: Well i have a loginModal() service which should return a promise on successful log in. this is my service code.